# Map_server fails to publish transform

Tags: slam, navigation, mapping, gmapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Map server node fails to publish transform when i execute the below launch file. All other nodes are functioning properly.

```
    <launch>
      <!-- Load the TortoiseBot URDF model into the parameter server -->
      <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find jmbot1_description)/urdf/jmbot1.1.urdf" />
      <!-- Start Gazebo with a world containing a large building-->
      <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/willowgarage_world.launch"/>
      <!-- include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch"/ -->
      <!-- Spawn a TortoiseBot in Gazebo, taking the description from the
           parameter server -->
      <node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" 
        args="-param robot_description -urdf -model jmbot1.1 -x 8 -y -8" />
     
    <!-- Convert /joint_states messages published by Gazebo to /tf messages,
           e.g., for rviz-->
      <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher"
            type="robot_state_publisher"/>
      <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server"
            args="$(find mapping)/src/maps/willow.yaml"  />
     <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_diff.launch"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find jmbot1_description)/src/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>

    </launch>
```

Below is my rviz results where the map's corner is oriented with the origin of rviz grid. I have verified the rqt_graph after launching the file, there is no transform published.

[image: image description]

I have added the amcl node to the launch file as instructed in a book and i got into a new error as below. Please find the edited launch file above.

> [ERROR] [1453990912.591443071,
> 49.843000000]: Couldn't transform from hokuyo_link to base_link, even though
> the message notifier is in use

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225239/map_server-fails-to-publish-transform/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map server does not publish the transform from `map` to the robot's links.
The map server only provides the map in the respective frame to be used by e.g. the localization.

You need a localization node (e.g. `amcl`) for this.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-28**:
Thank you for your clarification, please find my edit above

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-01-28**:
If this is a new question, please post a new question. I'm not sure I understand what your question is actually about...

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-01-28**:
I have posted a new question explaining in detail [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/225324/error-in-amcl-node-while-configuring-navigation-stack-simulation/)